# BufferedWriter writing many rows and causing OutOfMemory error

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

I have class that fetches a very large result set from a database, some 10,000,000 rows, which I require to write to a file. I have a logger that outputs every 10k rows, but when it gets into the millions it starts to slow down exponentially until I get an `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` error. I'm passing -Xmx6000m as an argument to the VM, also.

Is there any method I can use to prevent the above error? Is using the try with resources method not the best way to do this? Should I be using a method other than a buffered writer?

```
File outputFile = new File(incoming.toUri());
StringBuilder outputCSV = new StringBuilder();
try (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile))) {
    for (RowIterator rowIterator = tradesFromKDB.rowIterator(); rowIterator.hasNext(); count++) {
        outputCSV.setLength(0);
        row = rowIterator.next();

        for (String cell : row.toString().split("\\|")) {
            try {
                outputCSV.append(cell.split("=")[1] + ",");
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                // This is a result of the right hand side of an = not having a value
                // E.G. |consolidatedflag=|
                // In such a case a comma is just appended
                outputCSV.append(',');
            }
        }

        if( count % 10000 == 0)
            logger.info("Processed " + count + " rows.");

        // Remove the last to characters; the ending '>' and trailing comma
        outputCSV.setLength(outputCSV.length() - 2);
        outputCSV.append("\n");

        bufferedWriter.write(outputCSV.toString());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage());
}
```

**EDIT**

I've stripped it out to remove a lot of the junk to just write the row:

```
File outputFile = new File(incomingQPBEOD.toUri());
StringBuilder outputCSV = new StringBuilder();
try (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile))) {
    for (RowIterator rowIterator = tradesFromKDB.rowIterator(); rowIterator.hasNext(); count++) {
        row = rowIterator.next();

        if( count % 10000 == 0)
            logger.info("Processed " + count + " rows.");

        bufferedWriter.write(row.toString());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage());
}
```

The issue still persists so it's either the rowIterator or the bufferWriter.

**EDIT 2**

I've removed the write to the BuffererWriter and I'm experiencing no issue with the memory.

```
        try (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile))) {
            for (RowIterator rowIterator = tradesFromKDB.rowIterator(); rowIterator.hasNext(); count++) {
                row = rowIterator.next();

                if( count % 10000 == 0)
                    logger.info("Processed " + count + " rows.");

//              bufferedWriter.write(row.toString());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
```

**EDIT 3**

The data is returned is always very similar:

Processed 990000 rows.

```
<Row:989999 date=2018-02-14|time=09:21:01|sym=TEST|price=1000.00|size=0|ex=MSCI|ttype=NONE|execvenue=NONE|extime=Wed Jul 14 09:24:01 GMT 2017|gmdtime=Wed Jul 14 09:21:01 GMT 2017|consolidated_flag=flagtype|trade_flags=Num|extimeNS=2018-02-14 09:21:01.261320525>
```

It's always has that amount of keypair values.

The issue seems to come if I am assigning the value of `row.toString()` to a variable.

Assigning the below to a String causes the slow down and crash but simply printing the toString() value to a logger doesn't cause any slowdown.

```
try (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile))) {
            for (RowIterator rowIterator = tradesFromKDB.rowIterator(); rowIterator.hasNext(); count++) {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();

                if( count % 10000 == 0) {
                    logger.info("Processed " + count + " rows.");
                    logger.info(row.toString());
                }

                // declared outside try with resource
                s = row.toString();
//              bufferedWriter.write(row.toString());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Try by increasing jvm heap size.

Comment: did you try with using a buffer size when initializing the BufferedWriter object

Comment: Added buffer information to question; `-Xmx6000m` is what I pass

Comment: Why do you say it is the buffered writer that causes the OOM. You have a few things going on here : the DB connection (if it caches the rows, as many JDBC drivers and/or ORMs do), it might be the real cause. It might be the buffer (although you seem to reset it), it might be a single line that is too big... Test and/or profile piece by piece.

Comment: @GPI I've added more info to my question which narrows it down.

Comment: Thanks. I think you can even add a version without the writer, and see what happens.

Comment: It's probably not the `BufferedWriter` (after all the buffer is fixed). Just a wild guess : I had once memory problems with a JDBC driver when iterating large result sets because they were not TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY

Comment: @bwt and Nanor : like I said. JDBC caching :-)

Comment: @bwt and GPI, I've actually removed the write to the BufferedWriter and it runs without issue! It's definitely the BufferedWriter.

Comment: It's definitely the BufferedWriter... or the content you're passing to it. That's where you should investigate. On which row does it break, how big is the thing you're trying to write in this row, what if you skip this row (e.g. write only if rowNum != {the one to skip}), ... stuff like that.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely the content I'm passing to it. I've tried writing a String to it and iterating the row; it runs in a fraction of the time.

Comment: Do you have a sample of the output or at least the average number of fields in a row and total length of a row? I've often dealt with very large text files and people underestimate the about of CPU wasted doing GC on the millions of strings they create using split, join or even toString.

Comment: Can you remove the `bufferedWriter.write()` but *keep* calling `row.toString()` and see what happens?

Comment: I've added the requested to the question.

Comment: so it's not the DB layer (that's good news !) but I'm still not convinced it is the BufferedLayout. What happen if you remove only the buffering. i.e. write directly in the FileWriter ?

Comment: @bwt Same problem. It must be a problem with our database connection pulling the entirety of the results into memory.

Comment: @bwt see the OP's Edit 3, done after I asked to remove the use of BufferedWriter but keep the calls to `row.toString()`. It would seem that the toString() calls are creating very large strings. This string in each iteration is saved in a variable `s` (its declaration is not shown, but presumably somewhere outside the while loop). So if there are two consecutive extremely large strings, the first one would still be referred to by s (and therefore can't be garbage-collected yet) while the second will have just been created by the toString method. So nothing to do with BufferedWriter at all.

Comment: Try finding the maximum `row.toString().length()` and print it out at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Garbage Collection is not able to recover the heap efficiently (meaning that 98% of CPU time is spent recovering less than 2% of heap).

This probably happens because of the huge amount of data. Generally the BufferedWriter should flush to the underlying stream whenever the requested buffer length exceeds the buffer size.

It is not guaranteed to be an issue with the Buffer though, it could just as well be the Database Connection and you should probably debug it step by step just as GPI suggested.

It's quite an interesting issue that I never ran into. You might try to split your files locally to not have such large results maybe? If that's not feasible then maybe closing the stream at times and reopening could solve the issue by making the GC recover more of the heap this way.

Comment: At this point, there is no proof or indication that the issue is in the BufferedWriter itself.

Comment: You are 100% correct there. It might just as well be the database connection. (edit: or anything else really. I updated based on your input.)